# How do I use installable event-driven triggers on a standalone Google Workspace add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm making a Google Workspace add-on with Apps Script which creates a button that runs a function on any Google Sheet. This button should appear every time a Google Sheet is open.

I initially wrote the script as a bound-script, and it works fine using the simple trigger `onOpen` - but I need it to be available on EVERY Sheet for every user. So I created a new stand-alone script. According to the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), installable triggers should work for stand-alone scripts.

But when I try to create an installable trigger, the only options in the `event source` drop down are "Time-driven" and "From calendar". Why is there only two options? Where is the `onOpen` equivalent trigger?

[image]

Comment: 1. Is your question about Google Workspace Add-On or Google Workspace Editor Add-Ons? 2. What do you mean by "this button" and by "Sheet" (do you mean spreadsheet / file /workbook or sheet / tab / worksheet ? (the best is to add a [mcve]). 3. What is the pretty basic workflow for using your "add-on" / "editor add-on" a more specifically the "button"?

Comment: @Rubén Thank you, you're right - I'll make sure I'm more clear with an example.

Comment: @Rubén According to [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types) there is no "Google Workspace Editor Add-Ons", just workplace add-ons and editor add-ons. But either way, I'm not sure how that is relevant because both types of add-ons should allow the functionality my add-on enables. But I believe my add-on is currently a "Workplace add-on"

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There is no way through the web user interface to create event-driven installable triggers for stand-alone projects in Google Apps Script. The way to do that is by using the Script Service

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
.forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet) // or .forDocument(document) etc.
.onOpen()
.create()
```

Installable event-driven triggers are linked to specific spreadsheets (or document, or form or presentation), so your script should read all the user spreadsheets and create a trigger for each of them and someway repeat this every certain time to do the same for new spreadsheets.

Considering that a user could have a really big number of spreadsheets you have to set a proper way to handle the script execution time limit among other things.

Comment: The web interface for Google Sheets has this as an option. But Slides (and Workspace, based on OP question) does not. Also, the OP is asking about Workspace. I'm trying to do this for Slides and `.forSlides` is not a function, so is an onOpen style installable trigger just not possible for slides?

Comment: Can't delete my comment, but I see on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers it says "Google Sheets, Slides, Forms, and Docs all support simple open triggers, but only Sheets, Docs and Forms support installable open triggers". I still don't understand WHY... but it answers my question.

Comment: How is this supposed to fire on *every* spreadsheet when you have to specify a spreadsheet ID in `.forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)`?

Comment: @zakdances Better to submit a feature request directly to Google. If you need further help, please post a new question.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you, but I'm still unclear. My question says `This button should appear every time a Google Sheet is open.` so I'm wondering how your answer accomplishes that if I have to specify a specific ID. Are you saying that this is not possible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create it [programatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) instead? I think that way you may avoid any problem with the web UI.