How to create menu items on Google Sheets through non-bound scripts?
Is there any way we can create menu items in Google Sheets through "non-bound" (standalone) scripts?  I read some official documentation on getUI, but found nothing so far in regards to non-bound scripts.  The following was my initial attempt, but no menu item is generating on my Google Sheet...

function onOpen() {

  const id = "1AHHRp0YNltB...";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const tab = sheet.getSheetByName("results");
  const menu = sheet.getUi();
  menu.createMenu("send email").addItem("Approve", "approver").addToUi();

  function appover() {
    const id = "1AHHRp0YNltB...";
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    const menu = sheet.getUi();
    const res = menu.alert("Okay?", menu.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  }

}



Update
With feedback/resources provided so far (thanks!), I'm trying my best to craft an installable open trigger programmatically with little documentation support on the how-to. Here is my latest effort...but no menu item displaying in my Google Sheet yet.  How far off am I?
function mTrigger() {
  var ssid = "1AHHRp0YNltB_TOJftIX9...";
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("mSheetMenu").forSpreadsheet(ssid)
  .onOpen()
  .create();
}

function mSheetMenu(event) {
  event.createMenu("send email").addItem("Approve", "approver").addToUi();
  function approver() {
    console.log("show me something");
  }
}



As Tanaike mentioned below, I'm coming into this question with the following background:

I have a Google Apps Script project of the standalone type and a Google Spreadsheet as the independent files, respectively.

I want to create a custom menu from the Google Apps Script project of the standalone type to the Google Spreadsheet.

Also, I want to make users execute the function in the Google Apps Script project of the standalone type from the created custom menu on the Spreadsheet.



I believe your situation is as follows.

You have a Google Apps Script project of the standalone type and a Google Spreadsheet as the independent files, respectively.
You want to create a custom menu from the Google Apps Script project of the standalone type to the Google Spreadsheet.
Also, you want to make users execute the function in the Google Apps Script project of the standalone type from the created custom menu on the Spreadsheet.

First, I think that Wicket's answer is useful. Ref In this answer, I would like to explain the modification points of your showing script. When I saw your showing script, I thought of the following modification points.
Modification points:

In your showing script, there is no method createMenu in the event object event. By this, the custom menu is not created. I guess that an error like event.createMenu is not a function occurs.
Even when the custom menu is created, the function approver is not run. Because function approver() {,,,} is included in the function mSheetMenu.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function mTrigger() {
  var ssid = "###"; // Please set your SpreadsheetID.
  var functionName = "mSheetMenu";

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forSpreadsheet(ssid).onOpen().create();
}

function mSheetMenu(event) {
  event.source.addMenu("send email", [{ name: "Approve", functionName: "approver" }]);
}

function approver() {
  console.log("show me something");
  Browser.msgBox("ok");
}


If you want to use the event object event, please use the above-modified script.

If you want to use createMenu, please modify event.source.addMenu("send email", [{ name: "Approve", functionName: "approver" }]); to SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("send email").addItem("Approve", "approver").addToUi();. Both results are the same.

In order to avoid the duplicated installable triggers, I updated the function mTrigger.


Testing:

Run mTrigger.
Open Spreadsheet.
When you open the Spreadsheet, you can see the created custom menu "mSheetMenu".
When you run "Approve" from the custom menu, you can see an opened dialog on the Spreadsheet. By this, you can confirm that the function approver in the Google Apps Script project of the standalone type is run.

Note:

In the current stage, when a custom menu is created by the trigger installed from the outside of Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, and so on), the function in the Google Apps Script project that the trigger is run.

References:

addMenu(name, subMenus) of Class Spreadsheet
createMenu(caption) of Class UI


Tanaike I can't thank you enough for your shared thoughts.  Your first 3 bullet points is my "exact" situation. I'll test out this process shortly.

This was a perfect learning opportunity for me. I will be coming back to this post for a while to soak in this educational usage for future projects. Thanks again!

@klewis Thank you for replying. When these answers to your question are useful, we are glad. Thank you, too.

Use an on-open installable trigger to add a menu to a spreadsheet from a stand-alone project. You could "hardcode" the spreadsheet URL or ID, but you might use the Drive Service to search for the spreadsheet, among other options.
Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.
From the above link

An installable open trigger runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that they have permission to edit.

...

You can use installable triggers in standalone and bound scripts. For example, a standalone script can programmatically create an installable trigger for an arbitrary Google Sheets file by calling TriggerBuilder.forSpreadsheet(key) and passing in the spreadsheet's ID.


onOpen is a reserved function name intended for a simple trigger. Considering this, it might be better to use a different function name for the function called by the on open installable trigger.
A more complex alternative is to publish an add-on using a stand-alone project. This might be overkill if you only use the menu in one spreadsheet.
Related

Best way to create and manage someone's triggers (GAS)
Is there any way to automatically create installable triggers?
Correct way to implement Installable Triggers in Google Addon (Google App Script)


Your references are helpful, but you spoke more words to my issue here in a previous discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887434/957186 | because I'm dealing with spreadsheets, and want to work with standalone scripts...

That developer documentation on installable triggers shows some introduction to  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction'), but never shows us "how to use" myFunction in conjuction to that statement...

Regardless, Your references and previous discussions was a good start for me. +1
